# Dissable autocommit in sql developer web. Autonomous Database - Oracle cloud

Tags: sql, oracle, autocommit, oracle-cloud-functions

I am doing some tests in Oracle Cloud using SQL Developer web.

I want to use the rollback command, but it does not work.

My table "t_test" is empty:

[image]

I add a row:

[image]

I can select that row:

[image]

I want to rollback:

[image]

It seems to work, but the record does not dissapear:

[image]

How can I dissable the autocommit?

**UPDATE**.

I tried to use set autocommit off, and it did not work

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't used SQL Developer on the web but I'd expect `set autocommit off` to work

Comment: @JustinCave Thanks. I tried that command with admin user also and it did not work. I updated the post.